# Adding a Portion of Info From One Cell to Another in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to "calculate" a value from one cell in an excel file to get the value to go into another cell. I know how to do this with numbers, but the cell I need to get information from is in a text format. I have a column of cells containing text on a variety of different things (popup info from a kml file), a portion of it states the heights I need to add to another cell, "H: 5" or "H: 16" for example. Depending on the size of the number, my goal is to calculate from this whether it's of small, medium, or large size in another column, or at least add the number itself to the other column if that's not possible.
Something along the lines of *IF A2 contains a value between 2 and 4 THEN B2 = small* or *IF A2 contains a value between 5 and 10 THEN B2 = Medium*. I can't figure out how to accomplish this though.

An example is shown in the image below. I want to extract the number following the "H: " in the PopupInfo column and add either that number or the size associated with it to the size column.

[example cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqG1t.png)

Comment: Formula in target cell (B2):
=IF(A1<=4;"small";IF(AND(A1>4;A1<=10);"medium";"");"")

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Capt.Krusty, but do you know if there's a way to accomplish this if there's more information in the cell I need to get the number from than just the number? I need to extract the number from the text and then run the operation on it somehow. I added a image to the original question that shows what I mean.

Comment: Can you uplaod an image of what the cells look like. Because extracting a number from similar strings is not hard and then I give you new input/formulas.

Comment: Certainly. I just added a link to the original question. It shows A1 - C3.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how to do this in excel, but I did manage to find a way to accomplish it in ArcGIS Pro, which works for the tasks I needed.

Comment: If "H: " is unique to the string and if the number is always followed by "<", then you can try to extract the number with `=MID(text_cell,FIND("H: ",text_cell)+LEN("H: "),FIND("<",text_cell,FIND("H: ",E4)+LEN("H: "))-(FIND("H: ",E4)+LEN("H: ")))